# Neural network for bidding in a card game using Encog

Tags: c#, neural-network, encog

I'd like to use Encog to train a neural network on the data at this [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67726/BidTraining.csv). There are 17 input features (2 numeric, 15 categorical) and 2 output features (both categorical).

I'd like to create a basic feedforward network that solves this problem, but my efforts so far have failed to converge. The design of my network is:

- Input layer: 57 nodes

  - 2 nodes for the score in columns A-B
  - 3 nodes for the prior bids in columns C-E (using -1 for None, 0 for Pass, 2 for Two, and 3 for Three)
  - 52 nodes for the 6 cards in columns G-Q (in a "six-hot" vector)
- Hidden layer: 104 nodes (just a guess based on 2 * 57)
- Output layer: 13 nodes (3 non-pass bids * 4 suits + 1 pass bid)

I'm using tanh as an activation function and have enabled bias nodes. The call to create this network (in C#) is:

```
Encog.Util.Simple.EncogUtility.SimpleFeedForward(nInputs, nHidden, 0, nOutputs, true)
```

I'm new to neural networks, so I'm really not sure how to approach this. So far, I've just been using trial and error, but I'm hoping there's a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I inputted your data in the code below.  I'm getting training errors and will see if I can solve the issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;


using Encog.Neural.Networks;
using Encog.Neural.Networks.Layers;
using Encog.Engine.Network.Activation;
using Encog.ML.Data;
using Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Resilient;
using Encog.ML.Train;
using Encog.ML.Data.Basic;
using Encog;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;


namespace encog_sample_csharp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Input for the XOR function.
        /// </summary>
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\BidTraining.csv";

        static DataTable dt = null;
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader();
            DataSet ds = reader.ReadCSVFile(FILENAME, true);
            dt = ds.Tables["Table1"];


            // create a neural network, without using a factory
            var network = new BasicNetwork();
            network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(null, true, 17));
            network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), false, 2));
            network.Structure.FinalizeStructure();
            network.Reset();
            Dictionarys dict = new Dictionarys();

            // create training dat
            IMLDataSet dataSet = dict.GetDataSet(dt);

            // train the neural network
            IMLTrain train = new ResilientPropagation(network, dataSet);

            int epoch = 1;

            do
            {
                train.Iteration();
                Console.WriteLine(@"Epoch #" + epoch + @" Error:" + train.Error);
                epoch++;
            } while (train.Error > 0.01);

            train.FinishTraining();

            // test the neural network
            Console.WriteLine(@"Neural Network Results:");
            foreach (IMLDataPair pair in dataSet)
            {
                IMLData output = network.Compute(pair.Input);
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Input[0] + @"," + pair.Input[1]
                                  + @", actual=" + output[0] + @",ideal=" + pair.Ideal[0]);
            }

            EncogFramework.Instance.Shutdown();
        }
    }
    public class Dictionarys
    {
        public double[][] inputNeurons;
        public double[][] outputNeurons;
        public static Dictionary<string, double> bid = new Dictionary<string, double>(){
             {"None", -1.0},
             {"Pass", 0.0},
             {"One", 1.0},
             {"Two", 2.0},
             {"Three", 3.0},
             {"Four", 4.0},
             {"Five", 5.0},
             {"Six", 6.0}
        };
        public static Dictionary<string, double> rank = new Dictionary<string, double>() {
            {"Ace", 1.0},
            {"Two", 2.0},
            {"Three", 3.0},
            {"Four", 4.0},
            {"Five", 5.0},
            {"Six", 6.0},
            {"Seven", 7.0},
            {"Eight", 8.0},
            {"Nine", 9.0},
            {"Ten", 10.0},
            {"Jack", 11.0},
            {"Queen", 12.0},
            {"King", 13.0}
        };
        public static Dictionary<string, double> suit = new Dictionary<string, double>() {
            {"None",-1.0},
            {"SuitA",1.0},
            {"SuitB",2.0},
            {"SuitC",3.0},
            {"SuitD",4.0}
        };

        public IMLDataSet GetDataSet(DataTable dt)
        {
            inputNeurons = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new[] {
                (double)x.Field<int>(0),
                (double)x.Field<int>(1),
                bid[x.Field<string>(2)],
                bid[x.Field<string>(3)],
                bid[x.Field<string>(4)],
                rank[x.Field<string>(5)],
                suit[x.Field<string>(6)],
                rank[x.Field<string>(7)],
                suit[x.Field<string>(8)],
                rank[x.Field<string>(9)],
                suit[x.Field<string>(10)],
                rank[x.Field<string>(11)],
                suit[x.Field<string>(12)],
                rank[x.Field<string>(13)],
                suit[x.Field<string>(14)],
                rank[x.Field<string>(15)],
                suit[x.Field<string>(16)]
            }).ToArray();

            outputNeurons = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new[] {
                bid[x.Field<string>(17)],
                suit[x.Field<string>(18)]
            }).ToArray();

            IMLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(inputNeurons, outputNeurons);    
            return trainingSet;
        }


    }
    public class CSVReader
    {

        public DataSet ReadCSVFile(string fullPath, bool headerRow)
        {

            string path = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string filename = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    string ConStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited\\\"", path, headerRow ? "Yes" : "No");
                    string SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", filename);
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, ConStr);
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "TextFile");
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
                }
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns)
                {
                    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code works, but the training loops forever.  I'm not using SimpleFeedForward() which may train better than sample code at Encog webpage.  I think I'm having same converge error you are having.

Comment: My code is converging ~2.  If you change the while loop criteria (train.Error > 2.1 instead of 0.01) you may get results.  The example I based the code on was performing an exclusive OR which is 100% defined.  You inputs are not 100% defined so the convergence number is higher.  As more bids are added to the inputs the train error should go down..